# What's the difference between entering return, option (⌥) + return and ctrl + return in TextEdit?

Tags: text, text-editor, textedit, formatting

I don't seen anything different like below picture.

[image]

Comment: There is no difference!

Comment: I don't see why this is flagged as unclear...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Viewing two example files in TextEdit there is indeed no difference:

On the left side `Rich Text` and on the right side `Simple Text`
`Keyboard Layout`: de-de

[image: textedit]

Viewing the same files with `TextWrangler` ("showing invisibles" enabled) the differences are revealed:

[image: textwrangler]

Viewing only the text file with `TextWrangler` ("hiding invisibles" enabled):

[image: textwranglertxtonly]

the same file in HexFiend:

[image: hexfiend]

<kbd>Return</kbd> and <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd> insert 0x0A (New Line) and <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd> inserts 0xE2 0x80 0xA8 (Code Point Value: 2028, Unicode Name: Line Separator)

The difference is visible here:

[image: textwrangler]

Inserting a lot of <kbd>q</kbd>s the whole second sequence of `abcdefghijklmnop` in the third line breaks to a "new line", while the same sequence in the second line continuously flows to a "new line".